# Android application unknown host exception

Tags: android

I developed an application for android tablets. In that application, when I get into the app and after doing some actions I keep the application idle for half an hour or sometimes and again get back into the app to perform any action, it leads to application crash with `UNKNOWNHOSTEXCEPTION`.I don't know why it happens even after i gave `INTERNET` permission in `Android manifest` file.I have been searching solution for this problem for one week...still i could not able to find any solution.i used fragments in my application...please help me...

Comment: POst your code and the request you are sending. Throw more light on the question.

Comment: Easy fix: Use try/catch -statement and catch the exception to prevent it from crashing your whole application.

Answer (score 1):

Likely the tablet temporary switching off the network to save energy. Add try/catch to your requests and probably do 2-3 tries in some interval before you will show error to user.

Answer (score 0):

This type of exception happens when you try to switch networks , or the required Network isn't available.

Use try/catch block to prevent crashing of application.